# How to troubleshoot a networked device with incorrect static IP address?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, static-ip

I have a Sony SNC-EP521 IP camera that's currently set to a static IP address of something like 10.0.0.x (if I remember correctly). The network I'm trying to place it in has IP addresses like 192.168.x.y, however.
There doesn't appear to be a reset button on the device. Factory settings has it set to DHCP, so that would have been nice. The only way to reset it (I think), is through its web interface or the SNC Toolbox software. Both require it to have a resolved IP address.

I'd rather not try and set my network to the 10.0.0.x range. I know very little of networking and am rather happy with how it is currently.
Anything else I could try?

Comment: Are you able to connect (from a laptop maybe) directly to the camera with an ethernet cable? That camera comes with a disk with `SNC toolbox` on it. Do you have that disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the installation manual that camera should have a reset switch.

> The camera can also be reset to the factory setting by turning on the
>   power while pressing the reset switch with a needle/paper clip.

You should see a small hole on the rear side where you can reach the reset button.

If you know the exact network settings of the camera you can take a PC, change the IP to be in the same network as the camera and connect it directly to the camera or a switch where the camera is connected. If you don't know the exact IP but you think the network is right, you can either use an IP scanner or some discovery software that should come with the camera.

---

*Quote: http://www.networkwebcams.com/downloads/sony/nwl_sony_snc-ep521_installation_guide.pdf*

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I think I had been reading the manual for a different model… :|